# sitecore workflow permissions

Tags: workflow, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-workflow

on the Sitecore Workflow and Security reference data sheets, i see these:

> **Workflow State Delete** controls whether or not a security account (user or role) can delete items which are currently associated with a
> specific workflow state
>
> **Workflow State Write** controls whether or not a security account can update items which are currently associated with a specific
> workflow state
>
> **Workflow Command Execute** controls whether or not an account is able to view workflow commands

So, i'm on the Security Editor, adding permissions to my creator and publisher roles, so it really makes sense to me adding Delete and Write permissions to individual workflow states, but i don't see an Execute column for commands. How am i supposed to set these permissions for the roles?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The image below should answer your question:

[image]